# How prove this inequality $x^3y+y^3z+z^3x\ge xyz(x+y+z)$

Tags: inequality, polynomials, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, sum-of-squares-method, rearrangement-inequality

> Let $x>0$, $y>0$ and $z>0$. Show that
>   $$x^3y+y^3z+z^3x\ge xyz(x+y+z).$$

I known we can't WLOG: $x\ge y\ge z$, if this, I can use rearrangement inequality, But other I can't it. Thanks?

Comment: Suppose for the time being $x\ge y\ge z$. Now observe that,

$$\begin{align}(x^3y-x^2yz)+(y^3z-xy^2z)+(z^3x-xyz^2)&=x^2(xy-yz)+y^2(yz-zx)+z^2(zx-xy)\\&=(x^2-z^2)(xy-yz)+(y^2-z^2)(yz-zx)\\&=y(x^2-z^2)(x-z)+z(y^2-z^2)(y-z)\\&\ge0\end{align}$$To justify the last step we use the assumption that $x\ge y\ge z$ and the hypothesis that $x,y,z>0$.

The other cases may be dealt in a similar manner.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AM-GM inequality: $\frac{a^2}{b} + \frac{b^2}{c} + \frac{c^2}{d} + \frac{d^2}{a} \geq a + b + c + d$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2072018/am-gm-inequality-fraca2b-fracb2c-fracc2d-fracd2a)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not assume $x\geq y\geq z$ because our inequality is cyclic and not symmetric,

but we can say that $(x^2,y^2,z^2)$ and $\left(\frac{1}{x},\frac{1}{y},\frac{1}{z}\right)$ are opposite ordered.

Thus, by Rearrangement
$$x^3y+y^3z+z^3x=xyz\left(\frac{x^2}{z}+\frac{y^2}{x}+\frac{z^2}{y}\right)=$$
$$=xyz\left(x^2\cdot\frac{1}{z}+y^2\cdot\frac{1}{x}+z^2\cdot\frac{1}{y}\right)\geq$$
$$\geq xyz\left(\frac{x^2}{x}+\frac{y^2}{y}+\frac{z^2}{z}\right)=xyz(x+y+z).$$

C-S also works because
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^2}{z}\geq\frac{(x+y+z)^2}{x+y+z}=x+y+z,$$
but you wanted Rearrangement.

We can prove this inequality also by $uvw$, AM-GM, BW and more.

Comment: so How to use Rearrangement?

Comment: care to explain the first inequality?

Comment: I have use C-S by solve it,because $\sum \dfrac{z^2}{x}\sum x\ge (\sum x)^2$

Comment: @wightahtl   windircurse I added something. I hope now it's clear.

Comment: @wightahtl Yes,C-S helps of course and there are other ways.

Comment: When you wrote that, "[y]ou can not assume $x≥y≥z$ because our inequality is cyclic and not symmetric", did you mean that "[y]ou can not assume $x≥y≥z$ **and use Rearrangement Inequality** because our inequality is cyclic and not symmetric"? Because, otherwise I don't see why can't we assume $x≥y≥z$.

Comment: @user 170039 See please better my solution. I am ready to explain, how I used Rearrangement. Read please better about opposite ordered things.

Comment: Your solution is perfectly fine. But I am confused on the part where you wrote "[y]ou can not assume $x≥y≥z$". What I wanted to ask was: even if I don't use the Rearrangement Inequality to prove the given inequality can I still not assume that $x≥y≥z$?

Comment: @user 170039 I did not assume $x\geq y\geq z$. I said only that $(x^2,y^2,z^2)$ and $\left(\frac{1}{x^2},\frac{1}{y^2},\frac{1}{z^2}\right)$ are opposite ordered. For which we don't need to assume that $x\geq y\geq z$, but it's also possible of course.

Comment: I believe @user170039 was trying to ask why you cannot assume $x\ge y\ge z$, though the sum of your responses have only come of the form that you don't need them, which doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: For the proof that $(x^2,y^2,z^2)$ and $\left(\frac{1}{x},\frac{1}{y},\frac{1}{z}\right)$ are opposite ordered we can assume $x\geq y\geq z$ because we need to prove a symmetric statement, but we can assume $x\geq z\geq y$ or we can use any permutation of $\{x,y,z\}$. The proof will be the same.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what is meant by rearrangement, so I'll offer another solution, fairly basic, but it works.
$$x^3y+y^3z+z^3x \geq xyz(x+y+z)$$
$$xy(x^2)+yz(y^2)+zx(z^2) - xyz(x+y+z) \geq 0$$
$$xy(x^2-2xz+z^2)+yz(y^2-2yx+x^2)+zx(z^2-2yz+y^2) \geq 0$$
$$xy(x-z)^2 + yz(y-x)^2+zx(z-y)^2 \geq 0$$
The last line consists of all positive values, and thus we can work backwords and show this inequality to be true.

Comment: [Rearrangement Inequality](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjd05XykfrVAhXFo48KHeEEBksQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FRearrangement_inequality&usg=AFQjCNHA7wSwN-uMpsDK1fnIvSAZ63hMpw).

Comment: Thanks! I will go learn about that now.

Comment: @Isaac Browne Your proof it's just AM-GM, which I meant: $\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^3y+z^2xy)\geq\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(2\sqrt{x^3y\cdot z^2xy}\right)=2\sum\limits_{cyc}x^2yz$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Thanks for that, $(x-y)^2 \geq 0$ is indeed equivalent to AM-GM. I just like to think of this as more fundamental as we see all the positive values on one side being greater than 0.