# Solving an inequality with Cauchy Schwarz

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

For positive real $a,b,c>0$ show that

$$abc(a+b+c)≤a^3b+b^3c+c^3a.$$

I am told that I should apply Cauchy-Schwarz, but it isn't entirely obvious to me, how I could do that in this case. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2408805/how-prove-this-inequality-x3yy3zz3x-ge-xyzxyz may help (I am assuming you are trying to ask this).

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3704336/42969