# $\frac1n\sum _{k=1}^na_k\to0$ if and only if $\frac1n\sum _{k=1}^na^2_k\to0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> If $(a_n)$ is a sequence in $(0,1)$, show that $\frac1n\sum _{k=1}^na_k\to0$ if and only if $\frac1n\sum _{k=1}^na^2_k\to0$

My try:

$\implies$: Since $a_k\in (0,1)$, we have $0\le\frac1n\sum _{k=1}^na^2_k\le \frac1n\sum _{k=1}^na_k$, and if RHS goes to zero, then by squeeze theorem, $\frac1n\sum _{k=1}^na^2_k\to0$

How to show other direction?

Comment: It is a well-known fact that if $a_k\to L$, then $\frac1n\sum_{k = 1}^n a_k\to L$ as well. However, the sum converges in many cases when the sequence does not. I can't immediately see how to address such cases.

Comment: For the other direction you can use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3192777/sequence-such-that-lim-limits-n-to-infty-fracx-12x-22-x-n2n-0

Comment: @MartinR, thank you very much.

Comment: @MartinR, how did you search for that question? I searched using google as well as the math.se search engine. But I was not suggested that question!

Comment: @Silent: I knew about that one because I had *answered* it recently :)

Comment: OMG :D Sorry i missed that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the other direction, we can use Cauchy-Schwartz:

$$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k}{n} = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}(a_k\cdot 1)}{n}\le \frac{(\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k^2)^{1/2}(\sum_{k=1}^{n}1^2)^{1/2}}{n}$$ $$   = \left (\frac{  \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k^2}{n}\right)^{1/2}\frac{  n^{1/2}}{n^{1/2}}  \to 0$$

Answer (score 4):

Your direction is fine. To prove the other direction first pick $\epsilon >0$ and split up the sum as follows, letting $\chi$ denote an indicator function,
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\,\chi_{a_k < \epsilon} + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\,\chi_{a_k \geq \epsilon}.
$$

Now $a_k \geq \epsilon$ implies $a_k \leq a_k^2 / \epsilon$. So we have
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \epsilon\,\chi_{a_k < \epsilon} + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n (a_k^2 / \epsilon)\,\chi_{a_k \geq \epsilon}.
$$

This gives us 
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \leq \epsilon + \frac{1}{\epsilon} (\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2).
$$

Now supposing $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2$ tends to zero, take the limit $n \rightarrow \infty$ to obtain
$$
\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \leq \epsilon.
$$

As $\epsilon > 0$ was arbitrarily chosen, you have that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ tends to zero.